# React native picker, get selected option text

Tags: react-native

I am using my react native picker with options like so:

```
<Picker
       selectedValue={student}
       label="Student"
       style={styles.picker}
       onChange={this.onStudentChange}
       options={
                categories
                .find(category => {
                     return category.id == year;
                })
                .options.find(category => {
                     return category.id == group;
                })
                .options
       }
/>
```

I then dispatch and action in my click handler, where `e` is the `id` of the student:

```
  onStudentChange(e) {
        if (e !== "") {
            this.props.setStudent(e);
        }
  }
```

**How can I get the selected option text as well as the value?**

Comment: Can you improve your snippet to show what `categories` looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the selected option by `id` from the list of options. After that you can get a text from the selected option. In the example below I moved the code that gets the options into a separate function which I also use in `onStudentChange`:

```
getOptions(year, group) {
    return categories
            .find(category => {
                 return category.id == year;
            })
            .options.find(category => {
                 return category.id == group;
            })
            .options
}

onStudentChange(e) {
    if (e !== "") {
        // Find option by id and get text.
        const text = this.getOptions().find(entry => entry.id === e).text;
        this.props.setStudent(e);
    }
}

render() {
    ...
    <Picker
       selectedValue={student}
       label="Student"
       style={styles.picker}
       onChange={this.onStudentChange}
       options={this.getOptions(year, group)}
    />
}
```